# Windows Data Types... why so redundant/undescriptive?

Tags: c, winapi, types, history

Could someone please exactly why the following `typedef`s/`#define`s have been defined? What value do they have, compared to the originals?

```
typedef char CHAR;
#define CONST const
typedef float FLOAT;

typedef unsigned __int64 DWORD64; //A 64-bit "double"-word?!
typedef ULONGLONG DWORDLONG;      //What's the difference?

typedef ULONG_PTR DWORD_PTR;      //What's the difference?
typedef long LONG_PTR;            //Wasn't INT_PTR enough?

typedef signed int LONG32;        //Why not "signed long"?
typedef unsigned int UINT;        //Wait.. UINT is "int", "LONG" is also int?
typedef unsigned long ULONG;      //ULONG is "long", but LONG32 is "int"? what?

typedef void *PVOID;              //Why not just say void*?
typedef void *LPVOID;             //What?!

typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T;         //Why not just size_t?
```

And, best of all:

```
#define VOID void                 //Assuming this is useful (?), why not typedef?
```

What's the reasoning behind these? Is it some sort of abstraction I'm not understanding?

---

**Edit**:

For those people mentioning compiler cross-compatilibity:

My question is *not* about why they didn't use `unsigned long long` instead of, say, `DWORD64`. My question is about why would anyone use `DWORD64` instead of `ULONG64` (or vice-versa)? Aren't both of those `typedef`ed to be 64 bits wide?

Or, as another example: Even in a "hypothetical" compiler that was meant to deceive us in every respect, what would be the difference between `ULONG_PTR` and `UINT_PTR` and `DWORD_PTR`? Aren't those all abstract data types just meaning the same thing -- `SIZE_T`?

However, I *am* asking why they used `ULONGLONG` instead of `long long` -- is there any potential difference in meaning, covered by neither `long long` nor `DWORDLONG`?

Comment: I would suspect a lot of these harken from the dark ages of win16, but I'll leave it to those who actually wrote windows code back in the ages of yore to answer :)

Comment: There are many things that influence the history of these types. When once defined, you can never take it back. #define VOID void was done, because originally void* was originally not in the C standard (can't find a link ...). So some compilers did not recognize it. But if you remove it now, you break code. And nobody wants to have his code break, when updates the SDK. There are already too many problems when updating, why break this in some old module which was not touched for 'centuries' but now suddenly does not compile anymore.

Comment: @Christopher: Oh, interesting case about `void`. What about some of the rest, like `char`? Was there any time when `char` was undefined as well?

Comment: The redundant definitions of DWORD64 versus UINT64 come to be, due to several teams in microsoft defining their own types. Maybe the kernel team liked DWORD64 and then the GDI team came and defined UINT64. Years later, when consolidating the SDK headers, the SDK team tried to get rid of multiple definitions and moved them to the same base header. This team could not remove definitions. So we have this 'mess' now. (this was a bit of guesswork ..)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most of these redundant names exist primarily for two reasons:

- they're historical types preserved for backward compatibility
- they're different names for the same type that arose from different teams of developers (it can be surprisingly difficult for teams to remain consistent across such a huge project as Windows)

---

```
typedef char CHAR;
```

The signedness of `char` can vary across platforms and compilers, so that's one reason. The original developers might have also kept this open for future changes in character encodings, but of course this is no longer relevant since we use `TCHAR` now for that purpose.

---

```
typedef unsigned __int64 DWORD64; //A 64-bit "double"-word?!
```

During the move to 64-bit, they probably discovered that some of their `DWORD` arguments really needed to be 64 bits long, and they probably renamed it `DWORD64` so that existing users of those APIs weren't confused.

---

```
typedef void *PVOID;              //Why not just say void*?
typedef void *LPVOID;             //What?!
```

This one dates back to the 16-bit days, when there were regular "near" pointers which were 16-bit and "far" pointers that were 32-bit. The `L` prefix on types stands for "long" or "far", which is meaningless now, but back in those days, these were probably defined like this:

```
typedef void near *PVOID;
typedef void far *LPVOID;
```

---

**Update:** As for `FLOAT`, `UINT` and `ULONG`, these are just examples of "more abstraction is good", in view of future changes. Keep in mind that Windows also runs on platforms other than x86 -- you could think of an architecture where floating-point numbers were represented in a non-standard format and the API functions were optimized to make use of this representation. This could then be in conflict with C's `float` data type.

Comment: +1 Great explanation! What about `FLOAT`, `UINT`, and `ULONG`? Why not just use `float`, `unsigned int`, and `unsigned long`? (Are `UINT` and `ULONG` fixed-size?) Oh, and is `CHAR` signed or unsigned then?

Comment: @Mehrdad: See my update. Now that you ask it, I'm not so sure about the signedness of `CHAR` -- my answer is full of guesses, but that's the best I can do.

Comment: @casablanca: Er... how is `INT` "more abstraction" than `int`? And, could you please give an example of how introducing `FLOAT` *might* be useful across platforms and/or compilers, even in a remote, theoretical sense?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Because defined types such as `FLOAT` and `INT` represent the types expected by the Windows API, which may not be the same as your compiler's interpretation of `float` and `int`. Remember that the API code is already compiled into the DLLs that ship with the OS, so any code you write needs to be binary-compatible with that.

Comment: @casablanca: Hm... so do you mean that they're useful if e.g. you use a big-endian compiler with a little-endian system? (I can't think of why anyone would possibly do this but I guess it might be theoretically possible...)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, even though that might never happen, those extra `typedef`s ensure that you can always change something if the need arises.

Comment: @casablanca: Really seems like overkill (especially because e.g. `FILE_BASIC_INFO` uses `DWORD` but `FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION` uses `ULONG`, so I have a feeling somebody messed up at MS) but makes sense, thanks. :)

Answer (score 9):

When the Windows API header files were first built 25 years ago, an `int` was 16 bits and a `long` was 32 bits.  The header files have evolved over time to reflect changes in compilers and in hardware.

Also, Microsoft C++ isn't the only C++ compiler out there that works with the Windows header files.  When Microsoft added the `size_t` keyword, not all compilers supported it.  But they could easily create a macro, `SIZE_T`, to express it.

Also, there are (or were) automated tools that convert the API header files from C/C++ to other languages.  Many of those tools were originally written to work with the current (at the time) header definitions.  If Microsoft were to just change the header files to streamline them as you suggest, many of those tools would stop working.

Basically, the header files map Windows types to a least common denominator so that multiple tools can work with them.  It does seem to be something of a mess at times, and I suspect that if Microsoft were willing to throw out any semblance of backward compatibility, they could reduce a large part of the mess.  But doing so would break a lot of tools (not to mention a lot of documentation).

So, yes, the Windows header files are sometimes a mess. That's the price we pay for evolution, backward compatibility, and the ability to work with multiple languages.

Additional info:

I'll agree that at first glance all those definitions seem crazy. But as one who has seen the Windows header files evolve over time, I understand how they came about. Most of those definitions made perfect sense when they were introduced, even if now they look crazy. As for the specific case `ULONGLONG` and `DWORD64`, I imagine that they were added for consistency, as the old header files had `ULONG` and `DWORD`, so programmers would expect the other two.  As for why `ULONG` and `DWORD` were both defined when they are the same thing, I can think of several possibilities, two of which are:

- One API team used `ULONG` and another used `DWORD`, and when header files were consolidated they just kept both rather than breaking code by converting to one or the other.
- Some programmers are more comfortable thinking in terms of `ULONG` than `DWORD`.  `ULONG` implies an integer type that you can do math on, whereas `DWORD` just implies a generic 32-bit value of some sort, typically something that is a key, handle, or other value that you wouldn't want to modify.

Your initial question was whether there was some reasoning behind the seemingly crazy definitions, or if there's an abstraction you're not missing. The simple answer is that the definitions evolved, with the changes making sense at the time. There's no particular abstraction, although the intent is that if you write your code to use the types that are defined in the headers, then you *should* be able to port your code from 32-bit to 64-bit without trouble.  That is, `DWORD` will be the same in both environments.  But if you use `DWORD` for a return value when the API says that the return value is `HANDLE`, you're going to have trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but please see my edit. My question isn't about why they didn't use built-in data types (which obviously vary by compiler... except for `void`, that one's baffling me), but why they have multiple names for the same abstract data type, such as `DWORD64` and `ULONG64` for "an integer with a width of 64 bits". Why would a **client** choose `ULONG_PTR` over `UINT_PTR`, or `DWORDLONG` over `ULONGLONG` or `DWORD64` or `ULONG64`?

Comment: @ Mehrdad - because there is nothing in the standard that says how big a long long is (other than it has to be at least as big as an int). DWORD64 is 64bits on anything from a 16bit windows to a 128bit Cray

Comment: @Marting: Wait, but then what's the difference between `ULONG64` and `ULONGLONG`? If `ULONG64` is always 64 bits, then why not use `DWORD64`? And if it's *not* always 64 bits, then why not use `ULONGLONG`?

Comment: Huh... that doesn't explain all of the types, but it's enlightening nonetheless, +1.

Answer (score 2):

One reason is to maintain some kind of portability between C compilers.

In particular DWORD64, in theory you just need to change the definition of DWORD64 to get the code compiling on other compilers.

Comment: Why not just use `ULONG64` everywhere? And what about the rest, like `VOID`? (I was asking about both the redundancy in the definitions *and* in the number of typedefs... is there any reason, even in theory, to use `DWORD64` instead of `ULONG64`?)

Comment: Different compilers have different "built in" names for 64bit integers. The VOID typedef seems a bit pointless though - can't explain that one.

Comment: @Jimmy: My question isn't about why they didn't use `unsigned long long`; my question is about why would anyone use `DWORD64` instead of `ULONG64` (or vice-versa)? Aren't *both* of those `typedef`ed to be 64 bits?

Comment: unsigned long long;  Because MS does not have this types. They stopped at C89 and unsigned long came later. Parts were introduced before any long was thought of so we have LARG_INTERGER or the like

Comment: @Friedrich: I'm not sure if you were answering my last comment, but that didn't answer my question of why we use `DWORD64` over `ULONG64`. (Others answered it, though.)

Comment: Because DWORD has a special meaning for Windows since ages. I think most of the question are covered at: